# Power Sources for outdoor electronics/electrical projects

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, outdoors

Very new to Electronics Fields but compelled by my obsession.
I would like to start with small projects which is very necessary at my house. I will explain some of my project ideas here.

## First stage

1. I would like to design a DIY project using Light Dependent Resistor which controls the light (very small light- 1 Watt cool white LED) on my backyards and/ or frontwards controlled by PIR sensors. That means turn the light ON when the sensors feels something/somebody otherwise leave as it is.

## Second stage

1. I would like to design a mobile app for a Bluetooth module that I would like to combine with Ardruino /PIC microcontroller to control the light.
   Since this is outdoor project, I am very much limited with Power Source.

Now, where I am bit hesitant about:

What should I use as a Power Source for my project?

I can use Batteries ( different Volts , 1.5, 9V etc) but what types of circuit I should be using so that the circuits make the battery last long or controls the battery voltage only when needed.
There are many components to think about like Bluetooth module, microcontroller, light etc.

Being a beginner, I am trying to avoid High Voltage if possible. I would like to mainly concentrate on DC sides at the moment.
I would be interested on elaborating my projects idea more and more but I am stuck with Power Source planning.

Comment: If you don't mind the size and weight a car battery that is not good enough for original use but still maintains a voltage of 12.6V or more when charged is liable to be "very useful". | Lead Acid batteries that will not maintain 12.6V or more are "very dead" and may be useful but will have very low capacity.  || Lithium Ion batteries with an appropriate charger are reasonably well behaved despite their bad reputation.

Comment: Low voltage outdoor lighting is a thing.  In the US just Google "low voltage outdoor lighting".  That would be an excellent starting point.

Comment: User3560453... You should spend as much as you can afford in writing out your hopes and goals. ***In detail***. Leave nothing out. If something is to be 50' away from something then say "A is to be 50' away from B." Make everything very, very concrete and detailed. If you need to do it, make a map. Power distribution is a huge issue depending on distances, power involved, or depending on the number of devices to be attached (it's very difficult to drive thousands of LEDs, but very very simple to drive just one.) I find very little to get a-hold of, so far, in your writing. Too many ideas flow.

Answer (score 0):

I would use+ power supplies from Meanwell, they have some that have 5v as an output and come with conformal coating, meaning that they are designed to be used for outdoors applications